# Please merge some tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

The following pairs of tags have the same meaning, and there isn't one that's clearly preferable to the other (if we delete one, it'll pop up again), so they should be made synonyms:

- [symbolic-link] and [symlink]
- [mail] and [email]
- [version-control] and [vcs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done, thanks. I made the less common a synonym of the more common in each case ([symbolic-link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbolic-link) ← [symlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symlink), [mail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) ← [email](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email), [version-control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control) ← [vcs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vcs)); the first was actually proposed ages ago by xeno before he was a mod, but it had no votes, so I just approved it

---

I also merged them all, so the synonym tags shouldn't exist anymore:

```
updating post history, 2 rows affected
updating posts, 2 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 2 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [symbolic-link] and [symlink] complete!

updating post history, 8 rows affected
updating posts, 4 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 4 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [mail] and [email] complete!

updating post history, 1 rows affected
updating posts, 1 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 1 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
merge of [version-control] and [vcs] complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 10 or more on the tag, can suggest and vote on tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

we moderators can't even force them I don't think... if we can would someone tell me how? Basically you'll have to vote on them

vote: [symbolic-link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/symbolic-link/synonyms), I wonder if we can make symbolic-link the synonym of symlink...

Comment: On the [proposal page](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) there's a link on the right of each unapproved one labeled "approve". You can also skip the process entirely and just [create one directly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/admin/create-tag-synonym). Apparently we never went through these, there are some unapproved ones from the beginning of the beta -- oops :(

Comment: @Michael I didn't know that was even there :(

Comment: As for symbolic-link, I'm fine with reversing the synonym direction, symlink makes more sense to me too

Comment: @Michael yeah I think we should redirect symbolic-link to symlink. esp because it's `man symlink`

Comment: Flipped it